# Show that $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_k(X_k -X_{k-1})$ is a square integrable martingale w.r.t. $\{F_n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

$\textbf{question}$

Let $\{F_n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a filtration and $\{X_n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ a square integrable martingale w.r.t. $\{F_n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, with $X_0 = 0$ , and such additionally there exists $C \in (0,\infty)$ such that for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$:

$E((X_n - X_{n-1})^2) \leq C$

Additionally, $\{\alpha_k, \ k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ denotes a sequence of real numbers.

Show that $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_k(X_k -X_{k-1})$ is a square integrable martingale w.r.t. $\{F_n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

$\textbf{problem}$

I don't understand how to show $M_n$ is a square integrable martingale $\textbf{with respect to}$ $\{F_n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Do I have to show that $E(M_n^2|F_{n-1})=M_{n-1}^2$ in which case I'll be fine.

Or do I have to show:

$sup_{n \geq 0}E(M_n^2)<\infty$

if so can I write:

$sup_{n \geq 0}E[(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_k(X_k -X_{k-1}))^2] \leq sup_{n \geq 0}E[(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_k^2(X_k -X_{k-1})^2]\leq M sup_{n \geq 0}E[(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_k -X_{k-1})^2]\leq ME[m(X_m -X_{m-1})^2]\leq MmC\leq \infty$

Answer (score 2):

For a process $\{Y_n\}_{n\in\mathcal{N}}$ to be a martingale wrt to a filtration $\mathcal{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathcal{N}}$ you have to show that :

- $Y_n$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}$
- $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|]$ exists for all $n$
- $\mathbb{E}[Y_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = Y_{n-1}$

<strike>So you have to show both basically to answer you question. The inequality shows that your process is $L^1$ for all $n$. The equality that it is a martingale.</strike>

Please do not ignore the first bullet point which justify the fact that you can write the left term of my third bullet point.

**EDIT**:

Sorry I misread the question and realize that only after struggling to prove Bullet 3.

What you have to show is that $\{M_n\}$ is a martingale and justify that it belongs to $L^2$.

**Appendix to show integrability of $Mn^2$:**

The two following propositions are not equivalent :

1. $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[M_n^2] < \infty$
2. $\mathbb{E}[M_n^2] < \infty,$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

The first is more restrictive and tells you that as $n$ goes larger, the quantity remain finite which is equivalent to saying that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[M_n^2] < \infty$

The second only tells you that the process is $L^1$ for all integers. So $1 \implies 2$ but nothing else.

To prove (2) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\mathbb{E}[(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k(X_k - X_{k-1}))^2] \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k^2 \cdot \mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - X_{k-1})^2] 
$$

From this I let you continue.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. If i show those three bullet points does that immediately mean that $M_n$ is also a square integrable matrix w.r.t $F$? Furthermore for bullet point 2, I thus have to show that $sup_{n>0}E(M_n^2)\leq \infty$ so are my inequalities correct?

Comment: I guess you meant martingale right ? In fact the question you asked was regarding $M_n^2$. And if you show the three bullets, yes, that means $Mn^2$ is a martingale. However, it does not tells you anything about $M_n$ excepts that it is a upper-martingale (with Jensen inequality and convexity of $\sqrt{x}$).

Comment: As for the inequality, it is not correct as is, in fact to better undestand, you have to show that your $\sup$ is finite. So your upperbound MUST not depend on $n$ (or $m$ or whatsoever). It is simpler than what you think. First bound by the upper bound of the values for $\alpha_k^2$ then use the information $\mathbb{E}[\sum(X_i-X_{i-1})^2] \leq M$

Comment: yes i meant martingale. Thank you I mostly understand now however I have one question remaining. If $E[(X_n-X_{n-1})^2] \leq C$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then shouldn't $sup_{n \geq 0}E[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-X_{i-1})^2]\leq sup_{n \geq 0} nC$? so since n is a natural number the sup of n is infinite right? so how do i get rid of the n?

Comment: Yes you are right that does not show that the supremum is finite. I edit my answer to give you the proper way to do so.